# Are there currently any spacecraft in orbit around Venus that might (or might not) be at risk of meteoric dust from comet Leonard C/2021 A?

Tags: venus, deep-space, safety, meteoroid

Astronomer Shreyas Vissapragada @astroshrey ​[tweeted](https://twitter.com/astroshrey/status/1419835939778482178)

> Check out the latest from [@aciqra](https://twitter.com/aciqra), [@Yeqzids](https://twitter.com/Yeqzids), et al (including myself!) on C/2021 A1 (Leonard) and its close approach to Venus:
>
> - [Preview of Comet C/2021 A1 (Leonard) and Its Encounter with Venus](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.1237)

The abstract ends:

> ...The flux of such meteors on Venus, and thus their potential direct or indirect observability, is highly uncertain as the comet's dust production history is poorly constrained at these distances, but will likely fall well below the meteor flux from comet C/2013 A1 (Siding Spring)'s closer encounter to Mars in 2014, **and thus poses negligible risk to any spacecraft in orbit around Venus.** Dust produced in previous apparitions will not likely contribute substantially to the meteor flux, nor will dust from any future activity apart from an unlikely high speed (>0.5 km/s) dust outburst prior to the comet reaching r~2 au in 2021 September.

Are there actually any active (or not) spacecraft currently in orbit around Venus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Akatsuki (JAXA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akatsuki_(spacecraft)) is currently active in orbit of Venus (since December 7, 2015), though it somewhat famously ***missed*** the first time it tried to orbit Venus. Miraculously, the mission team was able to setup another encounter with Venus (5 years later) and inserted into a larger (~11 day) than planned (~4 day) orbit. It is in an extended mission phase (["Latter Phase In Operation"](https://global.jaxa.jp/projects/sas/planet_c/index.html)).

[Venus Express (ESA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_Express) [ran out of propellant](https://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Space_Science/Venus_Express/Venus_Express_goes_gently_into_the_night) in late 2014 and has probably decayed since then, though impossible to know for sure:

- In mid July 2014 it was in a [63,000 km x 460 km orbit](https://sci.esa.int/web/venus-express/-/54915-venturing-into-the-upper-atmosphere-of-venus).
- By late November the periapsis (or *[pericytherion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytherean)* if you're posh) had dropped low enough that mission operators elected to try and raise it back up; this is when it ran out of propellant and subsequently lost attitude control.
- By January 2015 the periapsis was [predicted to be only ~120 km(!)](https://blogs.esa.int/rocketscience/2015/01/23/venus-express-the-last-shout/), this is roughly density equivalent to ~100 km on Earth, in a ~53,000 km x 120 km (calculated) orbit. [This was the last time ESA was able to detect the spacecraft's carrier signal](https://blogs.esa.int/rocketscience/2015/01/23/venus-express-the-last-shout/).

Comment: Oh Akatsuki! It seems I'd mentioned a photograph that it once took earlier this year in: [Has Hubble photographed Venus in near IR? If so how does it compare to the new and exciting Parker Solar Probe image?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41691/7982)

Comment: @uhoh this has inspired *[a question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/56136/40257)*

Comment: and quite an interesting one for sure! Now, about that "...missed the first time it tried to orbit Venus"...

Comment: I've just asked [What antennas does JAXA use to communicate with its deep space spacecraft? Does it have a deep space network of its own?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/56160/12102)

Comment: and [Osculating oscillations! What makes Akatsuki's eccentricity and inclination about Venus vary periodically?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/56161/12102)