# How did Venus Express' periapsis decay so quickly?

Tags: interplanetary, venus, esa, aerobraking

ESA's [Venus Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_Express) [ran out of propellant](https://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Space_Science/Venus_Express/Venus_Express_goes_gently_into_the_night) in late 2014 and has probably decayed out of orbit since then.

A timeline of events from my research for [my answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/56135/40257) to [Are there currently any spacecraft in orbit around Venus that might (or might not) be at risk of meteoric dust from comet Leonard C/2021 A?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/56131/40257):

- In mid July 2014 Venus Express was in a [63,000 km x 460 km orbit](https://sci.esa.int/web/venus-express/-/54915-venturing-into-the-upper-atmosphere-of-venus).
- By late November the periapsis (or *[pericytherion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytherean)* if you're posh) had dropped low enough that mission operators elected to try and raise it back up; this is when it ran out of propellant and subsequently lost attitude control.
- By January 2015 the periapsis was [predicted to be only ~120 km(!)](https://blogs.esa.int/rocketscience/2015/01/23/venus-express-the-last-shout/), this is roughly density equivalent to ~100 km on Earth, in a ~53,000 km x 120 km (calculated) orbit. [This was the last time ESA was able to detect the spacecraft's carrier signal](https://blogs.esa.int/rocketscience/2015/01/23/venus-express-the-last-shout/).

This dramatic of a periapsis drop relative to the change in apoapsis just doesn't *add up* in my back of envelope thinking.

The lowering of velocity at periapsis affects apoapsis height and, minimally, periapsis height. This is seen dramatically in the decay of [Komsmos-482 (1972-023E), via Jonathan McDowell](https://twitter.com/planet4589/status/1100581649018949633):

[image: High Earth Orbit decay]

The periapsis for Kosmos-482 (1972-023E) drops from 228 km (1972) to 199 km (today, ~50 years later!).

Though [solar cycle 24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cycle_24) did peak in 2014, it wasn't that strong and the [MSISE-90 Model puts Earth's density @ ~200km  at ~10e-9 $kg/m^3$ during high solar activity](http://www.braeunig.us/space/atmos.htm). Compare this with *[actual Venus Express measurements](https://sci.esa.int/web/venus-express/-/57736-density-profiles-of-venus-polar-atmosphere)* of densities around 10e-12 $kg/m^3$ @ only ~190 km altitude.

**How did Venus Express' periapsis decay so quickly?**

Comment: Maybe it wasn't decay after all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Venus Express (VEX) used a highly elliptical, polar orbit. A peculiar feature of this orbit around Venus is that the pericentre altitude will drift due to third body perturbations from the Sun's gravity (according to [this paper](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdfdirect/10.1029/2008JE003290)).

[image]

According to [this paper](https://issfd.org/2015/files/downloads/papers/097_Damiani.pdf) (and implied in [this press release from ESA](https://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Space_Science/Venus_Express/Venus_Express_goes_gently_into_the_night) marking the end of mission for VEX), mission operators had to regularly use propellant to raise the orbit's pericentre which would decay by as much as -5 km/day.

This seemingly could explain the rate of the spacecraft's periapsis decay.

Comment: Wow! and... wow! Great find, it's hard to imagine how it could be ~ 5 km/day, I think there's another question or two in this of the "How the heck...?" variety.

Comment: It seems my focus on atmospheric decay was misguided, I suspected this after reading [@Ryan C's answer here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/56218/40257), nice sources!

Comment: @uhoh with such a highly eccentric orbit it would really only take a very small force to change the pericentre altitude considerably.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto that could certainly be true, but it just *feels* counterintuitive to me for some reason, though I can't say why. Without resorting to math I'd guess that raising the apocenter would be easier, but perhaps the energy stays constant so the pericenter must drop to keep energy and semimajor axis constant. I'm pre-coffee right now so will have to think about that a little later, too few neurons...

Comment: From aerodynamics, it makes more sense that it would lower the pericentre quicker, but that isn't the only force involved, not by a long shot...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto No, just the opposite! For aerodynamic drag the pericenter stays relatively fixed; the orbit circularizes first by lowering of the apocenter. Velocity lost at peri results in apo lowering. https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21226/12102

Comment: @uhoh Ere, yeah, I knew that... Should get more sleep...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto ya I knew you knew; I'd offer you some coffee but the $1/r^2$ is too large.