# What antennas does JAXA use to communicate with its deep space spacecraft? Does it have a deep space network of its own?

Tags: radio-communication, deep-space, antenna, ground-station, jaxa

[@BrendanLuke's answer to *Are there currently any spacecraft in orbit around Venus that might (or might not) be at risk of meteoric dust from comet Leonard C/2021 A?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/56135/12102) alludes to [the exciting story of Akatsuki's near complete loss of mission and amazing recovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akatsuki_(spacecraft)#Operations).

Following the initial failure, communication with the safe-moded spacecraft was via it's low gain antenna, which would have required a substantial antenna on Earth.

**Question:** What antennas does JAXA use to communicate with its deep space spacecraft? Does it have a deep space network of its own? Does it use a mix of domestic dishes and those of other space agencies?

**Note 1:** Akatsuki's story is background only, I'm asking about all of JAXA's wide-ranging deep space program. There's a [short and not guarnanteed-to-be-complete list here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAXA#Lunar_and_interplanetary_missions).

**Note 2:** Wikipedia's [JAXA: Communication ground stations for interplanetary spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAXA#Communication_ground_stations_for_interplanetary_spacecraft) says:

> This section is empty. You can help by adding to it. (January 2020)

Comment: Maybe not enough for a clear or full answer yet, but various links point to DSN use [here](https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/heo/scan/services/missions/solarsystem/PlanetC.html), [here](https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/heo/scan/services/missions/scan_network/akatsuki), [here](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/nasa-scientists-applaud-japanese-spacecraft-akatsuki-s-successful-rendezvous-with-venus).

Comment: JAXA [appears to have significant tracking a comms infrastructure](https://track.sfo.jaxa.jp/en/index.html) with the [Misasa (Masuda?) station(s?)](https://www.isas.jaxa.jp/home/great/misasadocs/RSU-2020061-0A.pdf) boasting performance in between that of DSN 34m & 70m stations.

Comment: JAXA has a 64 m dish at  Nagano, which will be replaced by the [GREAT dish](https://global.jaxa.jp/projects/sas/great/) that will be constructed at Saku City, Nagano Prefecture. It was supposed to be operational in 2019. It will be 54 m diameter & will have an operational life of 20 years.

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer...

> **Question:** What antennas does JAXA use to communicate with its deep
> space spacecraft?

From: https://www.isas.jaxa.jp/en/about/facilities/usuda.html

(and mentioned in the comments to the question above)

> Usuda Deep Space Center was founded to transmit operation commands to
> deep-space explorers and to receive observation data from explorers.
>
> The location was chosen for its environment to receive faint signals
> from explorers at great distances with less jamming such as city
> noise.
>
> The center has been in operation since October 1984.
>
> The large parabolic antenna, the core component of the facility, has a
> 64m-diameter reflector and weighs 1,980 tons in total.
>
> The center also has a 10m-diameter antenna and a
> transmitting/receiving system to retrieve VLBI (Very Long Baseline
> Interferometry) observation data.
>
> Geographic Position: Long. 138o 21' 54EE, Lat. 36o 07' 54EN
>
> Altitude: 1,456m
>
> Area: 98,302m2

> **Question:** Does it have a deep space network of its own?

Yes:

> JAXA’s Usuda Deep Space Center, Nagano, ...has served as **Japan’s only
> ground station for deep space**.
>
> The Center conducts command transmission operations to deep space
> probes and receives observation data from them as they fly closer to
> satellites, planets, comets, and the moon.
>
> X-band and S-band radio waves are used for communicating with space
> probes. K-band will also be used in the future.

[image: Usadaimage]
(https://global.jaxa.jp/about/centers/udsc/index.html)

> Usada.. was used to communicate with Japan’s first two interplanetary
> space probes, Sakigake and Suisei, which were launched to study
> Halley’s Comet in 1985.
>
> The antenna has since handled communications with the asteroid probe
> Hayabusa and other deep-space probes.
>
> It is now being used to communicate with the Venus probe Akatsuki and
> the asteroid probe Hayabusa 2.
>
> Similar huge antennas are used by the deep space networks of the USA, China, Russia, Europe, and India.

As also mentioned in the comments:

> Because the 64 meter antenna is aging, JAXA is building a new antenna nearby.
> This new antenna, called GREAT (Ground Station for Deep Space Exploration and Telecommunication), also known as **Misasa Deep Space Station** will be slightly smaller (54 meters in diameter) but have better surface accuracy and hence be capable of working at the higher Ka-band frequencies.
>
> To **secure operational capacity for JAXA to independently achieve**
> innovative results **from deep space exploration** by newly enabling the
> receiving of Ka-band while continuing to cope with X-band
> communication, which has been used for a long time for deep space
> missions.

[image: GREAt3dimage]
(GREAT/Misasa 54m CAD image)

(The other tracking stations: Okinawa, Masuda, and Katsuura are for satellite tracking and control)

> **Question:** Does it use a mix of domestic dishes and those of other space agencies?

Yes:

> In addition to the Center, a similar large antenna for tracking and
> controlling space probes is possessed by other overseas space
> organizations including NASA of the U.S.A. and ESA of Europe.

From: https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/heo/scan/services/missions/scan_network/akatsuki

> The Deep Space Network provided communication and tracking services to
> Akatsuki through its 34 meter antennas.

[image: DSNimage]

From: https://web.archive.org/web/20110614133812/http://deepspace.jpl.nasa.gov/technology/95_20/95-20.pdf

> Like other outstandingly successful deep-space missions before and
> after, the Voyager Mission to Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, and Neptune and
> their moons and rings depended on the unique capabilities of the DSN,
> including the capability of arraying with non-DSN facilities at Parkes
> (Australia), the VLA (New Mexico), and Usuda (Japan).

Additional reading:

> Misasa Deep Space Station (MDSS)... will operate at X-band (8.4 GHz) and Ka- band (32 GHz). As part of
> ongoing joint support of deep space missions amongst JAXA, ESA, and
> NASA, ...are developing a united multi-agency effort to improve the
> X/Ka celestial reference frame as well as a unified X/Ka terrestrial
> frame to be **shared by the three agencies**.
>
> The Misasa 54-m antenna enhances X/Ka sensitivity by virtue of having
> an aperture area 2.5 times larger than the NASA and ESA antennas in
> the network.
>
> Misasa improves the network geometry by providing four new baselines
> including the first direct north-south baseline (Japan-Australia) in
> the X/Ka VLBI network which will provide optimal geometry for
> improving declinations.

[image: Misasaimpact]

> X/Ka (8.4/32 GHz) Celestial Frame:
> Roadmap to the future.

https://syrte.obspm.fr/astro/journees2019/journees_pdf/SessionIII_1/JACOBS_Christopher.pdf

Comment: blobbymcblobby to the rescue!

Comment: Seems 100% non partial!